# vue-cli 3 pages config will serve javascript but does not fire it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm running into an issue when trying to use the [pages config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) for vue-cli v3.

I have two pages setup, my index page and a test page:

```
pages: {
        index: {
        entry: "src/main.js",
        template: "public/index.html",
        filename: "index.html",
        title: "Index Page",
        chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "index"]
    },
        "test-case-study": {
        entry: "src/subpage/test-case-study.js",
        template: "public/test-case-study.html",
        filename: "test-case-study.html",
        title: "Test case study",
        chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "test-case-study"]
    }
}
```

I have my entry point files and templates in the (I'm assuming) correct spots:

[image: file locations]

And when I run `npm run serve` and navigate to the test page (`http://localhost:8080/test-case-study.html`) to check, the markup loads correct, the javascript file comes through successfully in the network tab, but I get the error

> The resource http://localhost:8080/test-case-study.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

The script tag is getting added to the head successfully:

[image: script tag added]

And when I look in the source tab at the javascript it all looks correct and I can see the `evaluate` function call with my custom javascript, but nothing ever fires.

## UPDATE

I ran an build and checked the output of the `dist/test-case-study.html` file and it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test case study</title>
        <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.96f8ab67.js rel=preload as=script>
        <link href=/js/test-case-study.d382d007.js rel=preload as=script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <div id=app></div>
        <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.96f8ab67.js></script>
        <script src=/js/test-case-study.d382d007.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's weird that the javascript is being pulled in twice, and I still don't get why it wouldn't fire. You'd think it would fire more than once vs not at all.

Is there something I'm missing from my config?

Comment: I encountered something similar. Did you figure out why?

Comment: It's been a bit so I can't remember exactly what solved it, but I know that I did need to make sure the entry point name for the page was included in the array of chunks to load and I did need chunk common. I know both of those were in my example image but I think at some point during troubleshooting I pulled them out and it worked after I put them back in it started working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also managed to fix it. I misspelled chunk-vendors as chunks-vendors. Sadly the build system doesn't complain anything.

Comment: @foresightyj - Exactly the same problem for me. Your comment solved the problem! chunk-vendors instead of chunks-vendors!